# Binding to DataGridComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I know this has been asked a few times, but I cannot get the binding to work on my DataGridComboBox, it never displays at all.  Can someone show me the error of my ways?

c#

```
IList<ServiceCodes> servicecodes = App.GetInfo.GetServiceCodes();
newinvoice.INVItemsDataGrid.DataContext = servicecodes;
newinvoice.ShowDialog();
```

XAML

```
<DataGrid x:Name="INVItemsDataGrid" DataContext="{Binding}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="INVSCDropDown" DisplayMemberPath="CodeName" SelectedValuePath="CodeName" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding CodeName}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Thanks for your help as always.

Comment: What kind of items are you intending to display in the DataGrid and in the ComboBox? These are two different things.

Comment: The ComboBox is meant to display string values from a List mm8.

Comment: Well, where is this list defined then...?

Comment: IList<ServiceCodes> hold the values for the list and I attach that to the Datacontext for the Datagrid.

Comment: And how are you setting the the ItemsSource for the DataGrid? Do you even need a DataGrid at all?

Comment: `<DataGrid x:Name="INVItemsDataGrid" DataContext="{Binding}">` - you set DataGridContext to the `Binding` which is DataContext of the usercontrol/window.

Comment: I am going to expand the Datagrid with other values, but to start with it requires a combobox for the user to select from a selection of codes.  I tried binding the itemsource to the same list but not luck with that either.

Comment: You need to bind something to the DataGrid for the ComboBox to get displayed...

Comment: Thanks mm8, so by setting the datacontext of the Datagrid is not enough, I have to bind to the itemssource of the datagrid instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is to set the `ItemsSource` property of the `DataGrid` to an `IEnumerable`.

Once you have done this, you could bind the `ComboBox` to another or the same `IEnumerable` like this:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="INVItemsDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="INVSCDropDown" DisplayMemberPath="CodeName" SelectedValuePath="CodeName" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding CodeName}">
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=., RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=., RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

...although it doesn't make much sense to bind the `ComboBox` and the `DataGrid` to the same source collection. But you should at least get the idea.

Comment: Thanks mm8 for explaining this to me.  It now makes sense.